# Import multiple text files to 1 cell and a new row in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import multiple text files to cells A1, A2, A3 etc.
This means text file 1 would go to A1
text file 2 should go to A2
text file 3 should go to A3

On stackoverflow i found a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476545/import-multiple-text-files-to-a-new-row-in-excel-using-vba) that looks almost like what i am trying to do except for the creation of new columns.

The problem is that the text strings in the files are delimited and put in new columns, as this is the purpose of the code (using the alternative given in the answer).

I don't know what to change in this code to put all the text of file 1 in cell A1. 
I hope it's possible, if not i appreciate any thoughts about other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish the entire content of each file placed into a single cell, the following adaptation of the code you referred to would probably work:

```
Sub Import_All_Text_Files()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim thisRow As Long
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim strInput As String

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Temp\Temp\"  'Change as required
    Dim strFilename As String

    strFilename = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

    With ActiveSheet
        thisRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Do While strFilename <> ""

            fileNum = FreeFile()
            Open strPath & strFilename For Binary As #fileNum
            strInput = Space$(LOF(fileNum))
            Get #fileNum, , strInput
            Close #fileNum

            thisRow = thisRow + 1
            .Cells(thisRow, 1).Value = strInput

            strFilename = Dir
        Loop
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I don't guarantee that it will work if the file sizes are too large - Excel has a limit to how many characters can be inserted into any one cell (32,767 if I remember correctly).

Comment: Your code actually does the job YowE3K! Im very surprised how fast you solved it. Also your remark about the maximum characters was helpful too. I noticed the code gives an error executing the line ".Cells(thisRow, 1).Value = strInput". The reason seems to be that the limit of characters in one cell is reached. Many thanks for your great help!

Comment: @bbgreen - If your file size is > 32Kb, you could possibly limit the cell value to the first 32Kb by saying `.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value = Left(strInput, 32767)` - it depends on whether you can afford to "lose" the remainder of the file or not.

Comment: Thanks for adding the 32Kb adaptation YowE3K. Your suggestion helps to avoid the error message induced by exceeding the limit of 32 Kb. I hope this limitation will be lifted in future versions of Excel. Now the code works without any error messages!

Comment: Hello YowE3K, I noticed that adding 32Kb as a limit for the cells is not solving the error message of insufficient memory as i thought it did. I changed it to a limit of 8192 and this works fine. For some reason this seems to be the maximum for the cells and not 32767.

Comment: @bbgreen  Actually, I just tested what happens when you execute a statement such as `Cells(1, 1).Value = Space(65555) & "a"` - the code runs without an error, but the cell only contains the first 32767 characters.  So my suggestion of using `Left(strInput, 32767)` appears to have been unnecessary as Excel is effectively doing that itself.  That leaves me with no idea of why you get an "insufficient memory" error, other than perhaps that you have reached the limit of RAM on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the following line of code should do it, since `curCol` is set to 1 (i.e. Column A):

```
curCol = curCol + 1
```

I would also like to point out the code you linked to is quite inefficient, since there is no need to measure the bottom row before each iteration. It really should be rewritten with a variable that simply increments the row number instead, to something like:

```
nxt_row = nxt_row +1
ActiveSheet.Cells(nxt_row, curCol) = DataLine
```

And the following lines of code should be moved to the beginning of the subroutine:

```
if Range("A1").Value = "" then 
  nxt_row = 1
else
  if Range("A2").Value = "" then 
    nxt_row = 2
  else
     nxt_row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row
  end if
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Miqi180! I tried the code and it works partially because it doesn't copy all the text of the file to the individual cells, but just the first line of the text. Nevertheless your code shows it is possible (i had some doubts).